# Bootstrap 3 responsive rectangle columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to accomplish this layout:
[image]

the left side is 33% and the right is 66%,
each button on the left side has 50% height from his width,
the big rectangle on the right side has 75% height from his width
and the blue rectangle is 25%

to achieve the divs height i'm using this method: http://codeitdown.com/css-square-rectangle/

no matter what i did, the left buttons are never the same height as the right two divs

http://www.bootply.com/Fc66vnIhOo

Comment: looking for a css solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve [this](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/mhdkf84u/) and you don't hate javascript, you can simply do this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="color1"></div>
    <div class="color2"></div>
    <div class="color3"></div>
    <div class="color4"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="color5"></div>
    <div class="color6"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.color1 {background: #01FF21;}
.color2 {background: #FF00DC;}
.color3 {background: #01FFFF;}
.color4 {background: #FFD800;}
.color5 {background: #01FF90;}
.color6 {background: #0094FF;}

.col-xs-4 {padding: 0;}
.col-xs-8 {padding: 0;}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    resizeBlocks();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        resizeBlocks();
    })
})

function resizeBlocks(){
    $('.color1').height($('.color1').width()/2);
    $('.color2').height($('.color2').width()/2);
    $('.color3').height($('.color3').width()/2);
    $('.color4').height($('.color4').width()/2);

    $('.color5').height(3*$('.color1').width()/2);
    $('.color6').height($('.color1').width()/2);
}
```

And don't forget to load jQuery!

Comment: Thanks! i want to apply this layout only between 600px and 900px. I have different layout for smaller sizes. how can i use javascript only between specific screen size?

Comment: Use this to get the device width: var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width; And inside resizeBlocks() function you should place all the lines inside this: if (width >600 && width < 900) {...}